# Connect to VPN via integrated MacOSX tool

Tags: macos, mac, vpn, openvpn

I have following openvpn.conf from my old PC:

```
port 11194
dev tap
remote vpn.company.com

proto tcp-client
tls-client
tls-remote vpn.company.com
ca  /etc/ssl/certs/CompanyCA.pem
cert    /etc/ssl/openvpn/me.at.candytech.cz.crt
key /etc/ssl/openvpn/me.at.candytech.cz.key

pull
comp-lzo yes
```

I would love to use built-in support for VPN in MacOSX like this:

[image: screenshot]

but I don't know which and where should I put these three certificates/keys mentioned in config file above.

Comment: Did you try seeking support from the VPN provider?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Brief answer: you can't use the built-in VPN client with these credentials.

It appears that the credentials that you have are for OpenVPN server, even the filename: `openvpn.conf` says so (however the standard OpenVPN port is 1194, which has changed to 11194 in this case). The built-in OSX client supports PPTP, L2TP/IPSec and Cisco IPSec (Cisco in 10.7), but not OpenVPN. You need OpenVPN client from [here](http://openvpn.net/), or if you need GUI -- popular GUI for OpenVPN is [Tunnelblick](https://code.google.com/p/tunnelblick/)

Answer (score 0):

They need to go in your user login keychain if you want to connect to the VPN from your user account, and in your machine's System keychain you want your machine to connect to the VPN even when no users are logged into the GUI console.

You can copy CompanyCA.pem to your Mac, and double-click on it to import it into the keychain via the "Keychain Access" utility app.

For your user cert, I don't know if Keychain Access can handle importing a private key separately from a cert, so you might need to use a tool like the `openssl` command to combine your `.crt` and `.key` into a `.p12` (PKCS#12) file, and then double-click that `.p12` file on your Mac to import it via Keychain Access.